# API Gateway - Allow passthrough only if number field is over a certain value

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, webhooks

I have a simple webhook from a form that is sent to API Gateway and invokes a function every time. Our mapping template is very simple as shown below:

```
{
"number" : $input.json('number'),
"url" : $input.json('url')
}
```

**DESIRED OUTCOME**

Anything below 90 for the field `number` will not invoke the Lambda function and the webhook request is blocked/finishes at the API Gateway stage.

Is it possible to add some sort of filter so only `number` over 90 gets passed through and invokes the lambda function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

In order to do it, You have to enable AWS API Gateway Request Validation and write custom validator.

You can validate **number** field in this way:

```
"number": {
      "type": "number",
      "maximum": 90
}
```

You can find more information here:

[Enable Request Validation in API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-method-request-validation.html)

[How to remove boilerplate validation logic in your REST APIs with Amazon API Gateway request validation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/how-to-remove-boilerplate-validation-logic-in-your-rest-apis-with-amazon-api-gateway-request-validation/)